# Refused to frame 'https://example.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'"

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm having a react page which I need to embed on other external sits. But I'm getting this error. I tried fixing it by adding this line. It's not working

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-ancestors *;">
```

Answer (score 1):

You likely have another policy, check your response headers. All content needs to pass all policies, so adding another one won't help. You will need to find out how the other policy is set and modify/remove it.